# "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context" in PHP

Tags: php

Why does this happen:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\phps\site.php on line 14

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="site.php" method="post">
enter your name :<input type="text" name="fn">
enter your age :<input type="number" name="age">
<input type="submit" value="click me" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && strlen($_POST["fn"]) = 0 && 
strlen($_POST["age"]) = 0) {
echo "enter your name and your age";
}
elseif (isset($_POST["submit"]) && strlen($_POST["fn"]) > 0 && 
strlen($_POST["age"]) = 0) {
echo "enter your age";
}
elseif (isset($_POST["submit"]) && strlen($_POST["fn"]) = 0 && 
strlen($_POST["age"]) > 0) {
echo "enter your name";
}
else {
$name = $_POST["fn"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
echo "my name is $name<br>";
echo "i am $age years old";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

to show text boxes

Comment: I would have expected to find a ton of duplicates for this, but I can't find any

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single `=` means assignment. You need to use `==` to check for equality:

```
// WRONG
strlen($_POST["fn"]) = 0 

// RIGHT
strlen($_POST["fn"]) == 0
```